# Sending requests via proxy (java.net.http.HttpClient)

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient

Is it possible in java.net.http.HttpClient send each request from a different proxy?
I need to do so that I can set the HttpRequest proxy through which it will be sent. Setting a proxy in HttpClient itself won't help, because I need all requests to be sent from different proxies.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: separate client for each proxy?

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или задайте его на основном англоязычном сайте https://stackoverflow.com